# Normalize nested JSON data with Pandas/Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I'm trying to normalize a similar sample data

```
{
  "2018-04-26 10:09:33": [
    {
      "user_id": "M8BE957ZA",
      "ts": "2018-04-26 10:06:33",
      "message": "Hello"
    }
  ],
  "2018-04-27 19:10:55": [
    {
      "user_id": "M5320QS1X",
      "ts": "2018-04-27 19:10:55",
      "message": "Thank you"
    }
  ],
```

I know I can use `json_normalize(data,'2018-04-26 10:09:33',record_prefix= '')` to create a table in pandas but the date/time keeps changing. How can I normalize it so I have as follow? Any suggestions

```
                          user_id.        ts                    message

2018-04-26 10:09:33       M8BE957ZA.      2018-04-26 10:06:33.  Hello
2018-04-26 10:09:33       M5320QS1X       2018-04-27 19:10:55.  Thank you
```

Comment: Since the key of the dictionary is repeated inside the dictionary why not creating your dataframe from `your_dict.values()`? Is your output index right? Where does the second row index come from?

Comment: Once I got the values how do I access the user_id, ts, and message? to create the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test = {
  "2018-04-26 10:09:33": [
    {
      "user_id": "M8BE957ZA",
      "ts": "2018-04-26 10:06:33",
      "message": "Hello"
    }
  ],
  "2018-04-27 19:10:55": [
    {
      "user_id": "M5320QS1X",
      "ts": "2018-04-27 19:10:55",
      "message": "Thank you"
    }
  ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test).melt()


    variable            value
0   2018-04-26 10:09:33 {'user_id': 'M8BE957ZA', 'ts': '2018-04-26 10:...
1   2018-04-27 19:10:55 {'user_id': 'M5320QS1X', 'ts': '2018-04-27 19:...
```

Read in your dataframe as your dict, then melt it to get the above structure. Next you can use `json_normalize` on the value column, then rejoin it to the variable column like so:

```
df.join(json_normalize(df['value'])).drop(columns = 'value').rename(columns = {'variable':'date'})

    date                user_id     ts                  message
0   2018-04-26 10:09:33 M8BE957ZA   2018-04-26 10:06:33 Hello
1   2018-04-27 19:10:55 M5320QS1X   2018-04-27 19:10:55 Thank you
```